# Format a BigDecimal so that 100 shows up as 100 instead of 1.0E+2

Tags: java, jsf, el, bigdecimal, number-formatting

I am outputing a `BigDecimal` using EL expression as follows: `#{beanActions.overallScore}`.

But when the value is `100`, then it appears as `1.0E+2`.

How can I display it as `100` without changing the type to `String`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works in my environment (Mojarra 2.1.3 with EL 2.2):

```html
<h:outputText value="#{beanActions.overallScore}">
    <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true"/>
</h:outputText>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking through [JSF NumberConverter](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_convertNumber.html).

Comment: This post can resume what I'm talking about http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/182862

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks for showing the way, I appreciate it. Matt's answer is the correct answer. Still its a pity, that people don't do googling for such simple scenarios (this question).